# TypeError: Uncaught error: letters.join is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is what i have in Nodejs

```
var freeSearch = function(connectionstring,collectionName,letters,callback){
   mongo.connect(url(connectionstring), function(err, db) {
    if (err != null)
    {
      callback(err,null);
      return;
    }
    var r = '^(' + letters.join('|') + ')';
```

i pass the letters as "234" why is that error?

Comment: You must call join in an array. You can try `letters.split('').join('|')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `letters.split("")` to convert that into an array, every element in that array being a single character, and then call `.join()` on it

Answer (score 1):

you can't call `join` on string. you can pass `['a','b','c']` to `letters` and call join on that.